# How to parse file with lot of json?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need to parse large file with more than one JSON in it. I didn't find any way how to do it. File looks like a BSON for mongoDB.
File example:

```
{"column" : value, "column_2" : value}
{"column" : valeu, "column_2" : value}
....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, but It didnt. All example parse only one json in file...

Comment: "parse each line to a Json object using json-simple" from top answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346512/read-multiple-objects-json-with-java which includes an example

Answer (score 0):

You will need to determine where one JSON begins and another ends within the file.  If each JSON is on an individual line, then this is easy, if not: You can loop through looking for the opening and closing braces, locating the points between each JSON.

```
    char[] characters;
    int openBraceCount = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> breakPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if(characters[i] == '{') {
            openBraceCount++;
        } else if(characters[i] == '}') {
            openBraceCount--;

            if(openBraceCount == 0) {
                breakPoints.add(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can then break the file apart at each break point, and pass the individual JSON's into whatever your favorite JSON library is.