# How to parse Json Array not separted by comma in java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I have a db.json file which is from a mongodb export. The json is structured like this:

```
{
"item1" : "test",
"item2" : "test",
"item3" : "test"
}
{
"item1" : "string",
"item2" : "string",
"item3" : "string"
}
```

As you can see it doesn't have a comma separator and it's not formatted as a collection of serialized objects.

I'm trying to Deserialize this db.json to a java class using Jackson but obviously it only parses the first pair of brackets because this is not recognized as an array in the standard json format. To be recognized it should be something like that.

```
[{
"item1" : "test",
"item2" : "test",
"item3" : "test"
},
{
"item1" : "string",
"item2" : "string",
"item3" : "string"
}]
```

I cannot modify the json manually since it's 15GB of text. This is what i tried

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Table[] tablesFromJSON = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("db.json").toFile(), Table[].class);
```

How should i approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/line-delimited-json-with-jackson-69c9e4cb6c00) can help you.

Comment: Can you expand on " cannot modify the json manually since it's 15GB of text." What are you planing on doing with it when it's fixed ? . Could you pre process with bash first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Table[] tablesFromJSON = mapper.readValue`

Does your machine have ~64GB of RAM installed? Because otherwise, any attempt to pull that stunt vs. a 15GB `.json` file is going to take a very long time and then keel over with an `OutOfMemoryError`, obviously.

I therefore highly doubt you actually want what you appear to be asking for.

Instead, you want to stream this data. Take the `InputStream`, use some JSON library to read **one** json object off of the stream, process this object in java code, and *not* by storing it in a gigantic `ArrayList` or `HashMap` or what not - in a way that it'll be garbage collectable after, and then read some more bytes out of the stream, just enough for the next object, and so on.

Thus: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870710/read-multiple-json-object-from-a-text-file) is what you want.

Comment: This actually solved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--jsonArray` parameter while exporting. More details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--jsonArray)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't export the file, I was just assigned to work with it

Comment: You can ask them to give a proper JSON. As this could impact other places as well, not only jackson would fail, but all other libraries would fail who follow JsonSchema.

Answer (score -1):

There is a java library to convert JSON strings to java objects. parse/generate JSON the way you want quickly. configure/validate JSON at every level.

Please refer to Quick- Json Lib https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/ has good examples as well as explanations.
May be this will help you.
[image: library sanp]